# AWS Rekognition with Android Studio - Cannot resolve method withEndpoint

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-rekognition

Working through AWS Rekognition Exercise 2: Detect Faces (API) but having a problem at the following line. From some reason withEndpoint won't resolve?

```
AmazonRekognitionClient rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentials).withEndpoint("rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
```

As best I can tell I've included everything necessary as build.gradle has

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.9'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.9'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.3.9'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-rekognition:2.3.9'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:+'
```

Has anyone had success with the examples in Android Studio? I found 2 related questions but one didn't include a completion solution and the other used Maven with IntelliJ. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example that you are referring to is using AWS SDK for Java. If you are using AWS SDK for Android, then the interface is slightly different.

```
AWSCredentialProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            COGNITO_POOL_ID,
            COGNITO_REGION
    );
AmazonRekognition client = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider);
```

You can also get rid of `compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:+'` in your build.gradle.

Comment: OK, wasn't sure how close should/shouldn't follow the Java example. Able to get through the example now. Thanks @Karthik.

Answer (score 1):

This Solution is for Android :

```
            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("YOUR ACCESS KEY","YOUR SECRET KEY");
            AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentials);
            rekognitionClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2));
```